# Where to find github template repository

Tags: github

I'm learning GitHub and terraform. I decided to make a "test" repository into a template by manually selecting the option "Template repository" under the "test" settings page.

But now I can't find the "test" repository template anywhere. The instructions I've read so far refer to organizations, but I'm using a personal account. Where can I find the template repository so I can edit it or delete it?

Comment: If it still exists on your account, and you're signed in as said account, navigating to https://github.com/<your+username>/test should work just the same as it would with a non-template repository.